# Why does Neoid rely on a relational database? How to use neo4j in RoR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, neo4j

I want to use Neo4J in my Ruby On Rails 4 application. Neoid looks promising. It is an Active Record Extension for Neo4J using neography.

I do not understand why I would mirror the data from a relational database to a graph database. I want to have the data in Neo4j to query much faster, but for what reason should I put the data into the relational database as well?

Besides that, do you know any similar solutions for Neo4J in rails which do not store the data in a relational database?

Elad Ossadon, the author of Neoid, recommended to use neology for accessing Neo4J without RDBMS, but this repository is very outdated and poorly documented.

Comment: Your writing is confusing. Are data on relational database mirrored to graph database, or is it the other way around? You are writing as it goes either way.

Comment: Neoid is *not* an Active Record Extension for Neo4J. It is an Active Record Extension for speeding up graph-like queries against an RDBMS by additionally storing the IDs in Neo4J, running graph queries against that and then retrieving the objects from the RDBMS via their IDs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't mirror the database. Neoid only stores the object ids in Neo4J for easier traversal, the data is stored only in the RDBMS. That's the whole point of Neoid: allow for graph queries on your relational data that would otherwise be very slow to do via SQL.

Comment: Oh. Here he is speaking about mirroring: https://github.com/elado/neoid/issues/9.

You can configure, which data is stored in neo4j with declare it in neoidable - isn't it?

So, why not store all data in Neo4J? Where are the disadvantages of using Neo4J only?